# invalid syntax error when running import nltk

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

The line "import nltk" shows invalid syntax for no reason. I'm trying to import nltk.corpus then "names" corpus/ I've been using nltk for a while now and this is the first time i'm getting this error.

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

> > > import nltk
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           import nltk
> > >         File "C:\Users\csp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\nltk.py", line 1
> > >           Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: Can you post the exact command you typed and the error stack trace?

Comment: i'll surely do that, but i only typed "import nltk" in the first line and nothing else. I tried the same thing in visual studio, I tried reinstalling nltk from pip.

Comment: The traceback only says this :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk